# How to custom draw selected item rows in Windows List-View Control

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have created NM_CUSTOMDRAW message handler to custom draw List-View control subitems. It is almost OK. However, I can't custom draw item which is selected. My custom settings are always ignored and default white text over blue bkColor is drawn.

Can I have any chance to custom draw selected items?

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully written code to custom draw selected item in CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT draw stage of OnCustomDraw() handler, and return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT after selected item drawn:

```
int subitemCount = GetHeaderCtrl().GetItemCount();
CRect itemRect;
for (int i = 0; i < subitemCount; i++) // Draw individual subitem
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        // My own function
        // calculate correct rect for first(index=0) subitem
        CalculateItemRect(nIndex, itemRect);
    }
    else if (!GetSubItemRect(nIndex, i, LVIR_BOUNDS, itemRect))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Adjust text rect to avoid overlapping with vertical grid line
    itemRect.left += 6;
    dc.DrawText(GetItemText(nIndex, i), itemRect, DT_LEFT | DT_NOCLIP | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
}
```

This code works so far so good. Any improvement suggestion is warmly welcome.